# UI Rezising Lags when Keyboard gone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm developing following layout.

[image]

When keybaord is displayed, the UI is resized to available space (state 'A'). When keybaord hides, the UI again resizes to fill the entire screen (state 'B'). But there is a visible lag in UI when  going from state 'A' to state 'B'. Is there any way to avoid this lag or provide smooth resize.

**UPDATE:** I'm using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in manifest for this activity. The given screenshot is actually a sample. My actual layout contains more complex layout which may be causing the lag on resize, but this one completely describes my issue. Is there a way to implement animated resize UI keyboard hide? Any help will be highly apreciated.

Comment: Not getting what have you try to do can you please explain more specific ?

Comment: @Haresh When I hides the keyboard, the area behind it stays blank for a few moments before getting filled by the activity layout. I want to avoid this blank time.

Comment: some lag is probably inevitable, since your ui and the keyboard ui are displayed by different processes whose actions are not synchronized with one another.

Comment: You should provide us with more information about your _real_ layout. Maybe then some optimization tips can be offered.

Comment: Please show us the adapter you are using and the layout xml you are using

Comment: Please provide a complete sources code of your layout. You have to simplify your UI to be drawn on less time. You have to override onConfigChange method and handle the Keybord Show/hide event to avoid your activity or Fragment re-creation.

Comment: Try using the "Method Profiling" feature in DDMS. It will help show you which methods are running too frequently or cumulatively eating the most time during that keyboard animation. Like the others have said, you will need to show us what's going on in the UI level, as it is common that perceived slowness is due to heavy work done on the UI thread in each loop.

Comment: Can't show the UI due to nature of project. But let me tell you that it's a `ListView` with complex layout. Also this happening on a simple test layout too, which I shown above.

Answer (score 1):

in your manifest file under activity tag just add:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustpan"
```

will solve your problem!!

Comment: I need to resize the layout for a few other fragments, so cant use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustpan"`

Comment: Tried with this but not helping.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Using it. But It's not helping